# Missing script :"start" while using npm start

Tags: reactjs, react-router

After creating a React app, while running a React app using `npm start`, raising error:

```
npm ERR! Missing script: "start"
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Did you mean one of these?
npm ERR!     npm star # Mark your favorite packages
npm ERR!     npm stars # View packages marked as favorites
npm ERR!
npm ERR! To see a list of scripts, run:
npm ERR!   npm run

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\91910\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-12-17T09_33_29_043Z-debug-0.log
```

package.json has "start" already:

```json
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

Comment: You can try running the command "npm run start" instead of "npm start". This will explicitly tell the npm to look for the start script. If this doesn't work, you can try running "npm install" to install all the dependencies in your project, and then running "npm start" again. @Asha

Comment: @CoolNetworking `npm start` is one of the few scripts that _doesn't_ need an explicit `run[-script]` (see also `test`): https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-start.

Comment: hmm, The issue is likely not with the React application, but rather with your npm installation. Try updating npm with the following command:
```npm install npm@latest -g
```
Then, re-run the command npm start and your application should start correctly.

Comment: Make sure you run this command in the root directory of your app